# How to set a collection with jekyll on github page?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I follow the official guide of [Collections | Jekyll • Simple, blog-aware, static sites](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) to add collections to my blog [wow-yes.github.io](https://wow-yes.github.io/blog/).

I have added the `staff_members` into `_config.yml`. All sources are stored in [GitHub - wow-yes/blog: my personal blog.](https://github.com/wow-yes/blog/)

```yaml
collections:
    my_collection:
        output: true
    staff_members:
        output: true
        people: true
```

and I also add the `jane.md` into the folder `_staff_members` .

When I tested it in my local pc， everything is ok. http://127.0.0.1:4000/staff_members/jane.html works well.

But when I open the https://wow-yes.github.io/staff_members/jane.html on github page, I get a 404 page [Site not found · GitHub Pages](https://wow-yes.github.io/staff_members/jane.html)

It looks like that Github didn't compile the `jane.md`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this question by myself.

This link https://wow-yes.github.io/staff_members/jane.html is wrong. The right one is https://wow-yes.github.io/blog/staff_members/jane.html. Github has compile `jane.md` but I didn't get the right link.

The `/blog/` is missing on github-pages address. Well, so I add `{{site.baseurl}}` into `_layout/collections.html` to generate the right url for my collection. It works well on my local server and github-pages.

The official guide [Collections | Jekyll • Simple, blog-aware, static sites](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) is right on local server. But when you apply this code into github pages, please add `{{site.baseurl}}` before `{{ staff_member.url }}`. For example:

```html
{% for staff_member in site.staff_members %}
  <h2>
    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ staff_member.url }}">
      {{ staff_member.name }} - {{ staff_member.position }}
    </a>
  </h2>
  <p>{{ staff_member.content | markdownify }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```